# Non standard syntax error in iterator? (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

```
void PointCloud::Create(std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point3d>> threeDPointSpace){
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point3d>>::iterator row;
    std::vector<cv::Point3d>::iterator col;
    for (row = threeDPointSpace.begin(); row != threeDPointSpace.end(); row++) {
        for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++) {
            cv::Point3d thisOne = col._Getcont; // error reported here
            vertices.push_back(VertexFormat(glm::vec3(thisOne.x, thisOne.y, thisOne.z), glm::vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)));
            totalData++;
        }
    }
}
```

Error message reads:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error C3867   'std::_Iterator_base12::_Getcont': non-standard syntax;
>   use '&' to create a pointer to member

What does this mean?  How can I fix this?  Am I not using this iterator schema correctly?  I'm attempting to access these elements.

Comment: try `col->_Getcont` (or maybe `col->_Getcont()`)

Comment: Looks like you forgot the parenthesis, or did you really want to assign a function pointer: `cv::Point3d thisOne =  col->_Getcont();`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use the function `std::vector<cv::Point3d>::iterator::_Getcont` without calling it (`()`) or using address-of syntax (`&`), which is indeed non-standard.

```
cv::Point3d thisOne = col._Getcont();
```

However, this function is from the internals of Visual Studio's standard library implementation (the leading `_` and the lack of a mention in [cppreference.com's documentation of the public interface for *RandomAccessIterator*s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) being the main clues); I have no idea why you're trying to use it. Just dereference the iterator, like everyone else:

```
const cv::Point3d& thisOne = *col;
```

Comment: I think it's the "Get Container" method which VS uses **in debug mode** to verify that you're not mixing iterators from different containers. (STL algorithms that take a begin/end iterator pair do require that these come from the same container, but violating this rule is Undefined Behavior)

Answer (score 1):

Since `col` is a `std::vector<cv::Point3d>::iterator` you would have to access an  attribute from the `Point3d` using

```
cv::Point3d thisOne = col->_Getcont;
```

and if this is a method, make sure you actually call the method

```
cv::Point3d thisOne = col->_Getcont();
```

Comment: It says the class doesn't have that member function, however, it seems i'm able to access the attributes via col->x and the like.

Comment: I can't find the method `Getcont` in their documentation, are you sure this is an actual method? Can you link the documentation for the method?

Answer (score 1):

Should not you use?

```
cv::Point3d thisOne = col->_Getcont;
```

Or if _Getcont is a member function

```
cv::Point3d thisOne = col->_Getcont();
```

Or

```
cv::Point3d thisOne = ( *col )._Getcont;

cv::Point3d thisOne = ( *col )._Getcont();
```

Or maybe you could write simply

```
cv::Point3d thisOne = *col;
```

because the type of the left object is the same as the type of expression `*col`.

In this case the function could be written like

```
void PointCloud::Create(std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point3d>> threeDPointSpace)
{
    for ( auto &row : threeDPointSpace )
    {
        for ( auto &thisOne : row )
        {
            vertices.push_back(VertexFormat(glm::vec3(thisOne.x, thisOne.y, thisOne.z), glm::vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)));
            totalData++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither of those seemed to work.  I got it by going around this declaration and just used col->x col->y and col->y.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow  It is unknown what is  ._Getcont. If it is a member function then see my updated post.

Comment: Ah, using (*col) works perfectly.  no need for _getcont!   Thanks.